# Disable Highlighting In A Web Page

Tags: javascript, html, css

I did an experiment like this:

```
<div onclick="clickfunc(this)"> highlightME </div>
<div> ooo blablabla highlightME ooo highlightME ooo highlightME ooo</div>

<script language=javascript>

    function clickfunc(obj) {
        var t = $(obj).text();
        doSearch(t);
    }

    function doSearch(text) {
        if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
            document.designMode = "on";
            // var sel = window.getSelection();
            // console.log(sel);
            // sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

            while (window.find(text)) {
                document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, "yellow");
                //sel.collapseToEnd();
            }
            document.designMode = "off";
        }
        else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            while (textRange.findText(text)) {
                textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, "yellow");
                textRange.collapse(false);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

When I click the text 'highlightME', it will highlight all occurrences on the page. However, the highlight will be always there.

I want to remove the highlighting by clicking second time on the text, or press ESC or via any other ways.

Doesn't matter if it requires either js, css or html changes.

~ thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var isHighLighting = false;

clickfunc = function(obj) {
        var t = $(obj).text();
        doSearch(t);
    }

doSearch = function (text) {
var color = isHighLighting?'transparent':'yellow';
        if (window.find && window.getSelection) {
            document.designMode = "on";
            // var sel = window.getSelection();
            // console.log(sel);
            // sel.collapse(document.body, 0);

            while (window.find(text)) {
                document.execCommand("HiliteColor", false, color);
                //sel.collapseToEnd();
            }
            document.designMode = "off";
        }
        else if (document.body.createTextRange) {
            var textRange = document.body.createTextRange();
            while (textRange.findText(text)) {
                textRange.execCommand("BackColor", false, color);
                textRange.collapse(false);
            }
        }
        isHighLighting = !isHighLighting;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="clickfunc(this)"> highlightME </div>
<div> ooo blablabla highlightME ooo highlightME ooo highlightME ooo</div>
```

Just add a variable to check is text highlighting or not and set `color` variable base on it.

Comment: Thank you. This is great! And I have a follow up question: assume I have couple <div> tags which contain 'highlightME', 'ooo' and 'blablabla' respectively. When I click on one of them, it could highlight the text I click and disable highlighting on the all other strings if there was something highlighted before.

Comment: it's ok if you `addClass` to texts instead of just highlight them, then you add jquery function for that class. it's very more complex than your current code.

Comment: I think I am close. But I found there was a problem in the example above. If you search 'ooo', it will only highlight the middle two 'ooo'  but lost the **first** and the **last** one. It confused me a lot.

Comment: I got it. When I click on text, js will get a string with spaces. A string trim could solve this problem.

Comment: congrat, I think you should mark my answer is correct :D